# unable to add or concatenate ' for the column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch account details in csv format.

My SQL Query is as follows:

```
select TRIM(ACC_NO), ACC_NAME, APPROVED_LIMIT, OUTSTANDING_AMT
```

The output is as follows:

> 8.00013E+11, HSBC, 500000, 10000

In csv, when I add 'before Acc_No, I can see the whole Account no like following:

> '8.00013E+11 --> 800013443902

But i am not able to concatenate the same in SQL Query but it's not working(Oracle). Could you please assist

```
select '''||TRIM(ACC_NO), ACC_NAME, APPROVED_LIMIT, OUTSTANDING_AMT
```

if i add anything else like , the output comes properly

```
select '\'||TRIM(ACC_NO), ACC_NAME, APPROVED_LIMIT, OUTSTANDING_AMT
```

> \800013443902, HSBC, 500000, 10000

Answer (score 0):

You can use two single quotes to represent one single quote as follows:

```
select ''''||TRIM(ACC_NO), ACC_NAME, APPROVED_LIMIT, OUTSTANDING_AMT
```

Comment: Then you can accept this answer. Welcome!!